# What about the equation $\sigma(2n)=2\left(n+\sigma(n)\right),$ involving the sum of divisor function?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-factorization, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

Yesterday I wrote this equation involving the sum of divisors function $\sigma(l)=\sum_{d\mid l}d$,
$$\sigma(2n)=2\left(n+\sigma(n)\right).\tag{1}$$
Due to its very simple form I don't know if it is in the literature. I try to explore it in the context of odd perfect numbers - in which I've created it.

**Claim 1.** If there exists an odd perfect number $n$, then it satisfies $(1)$.

Also, one can prove the next claim.

**Claim 2.** Let an integer $n=2^{\alpha}m$, where $\alpha\geq 0$ is integer and the positive integer $m$ satisfies $\gcd(2,m)=1$. If our integer $n$ satisfies $(1)$ with $\alpha=0$ then is an odd perfect number. If our integer $n$ satisfies $(1)$ with $\alpha\geq 1$ then $m$ satisfies $\sigma(m)=2^{\alpha+1}m$, that is $m$ should be perfect or multiperfect.

*Proof of Case $\alpha\geq 1$.* One writes from our assumptions and equation $(1)$ that $$\sigma(2^{\alpha+1}m)=2(2^{\alpha}m+\sigma(2^{\alpha}m)).\tag{2}$$
And using that the sum of divisors function is multiplicative then $$(2^{\alpha+2}-1-2(2^{\alpha+1}-1))\sigma(m)=2^{\alpha+1}m,\tag{3}$$
concluding $\sigma(m)=2^{\alpha+1}m.\square$

> **Question.** Is it possible to do more work on this equation? **Many thanks.**

I hope that my question is clear. I would like to rule out some case, or deduce a stronger result about the form of the solutions of $(1)$. Please if **this equation or question** was in the literature refer to it and I will try to search and read those statements. Thus I am looking for feedback about the previous equation, since it is an open problem I am waiting for some answer from your knowledges on odd perfect numbers about if you can get some statement in the exploration of the solutions of $(1)$, and I am going to accept the answer with more merit.

**Computational fact.** I've tested the solutions of $(1)$ using this code (this is a line)

`for (i = 1, 1000000,if(sigma(2*i)==2*(i+sigma(i)),print(i)))`

using this [Sage Cell Server](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/), you need to choice *GP* as Language and press **Evaluate**.

Comment: Many thanks @ArnaudMortier

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: Thanks to you @ArnaudMortier , I've written this formalism as a present for you, if you want to read it. Let $\rho$ an odd prime with $\gcd(\rho,n)=1$ (thus coprime to our odd perfect number) then previous equation implies that we can write the formal equation (as a consequence that the sum of dvisor function is multiplicative) $$\mathcal{D}(X)-2X=\mathcal{D}(n),$$ where we are denoting $\mathcal{D}(*)=\sigma(2*)-2\sigma(*)$ and $X$ as the dilatation $X=\rho\cdot n$.

Comment: @user243301, $2X - D(X)$ is the deficiency function.  (See [OEIS sequence A033879](http://oeis.org/A033879).)

Comment: Thanks for the comment I am going to read the OEIS's page @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris My previous comment was a remark about such formula, of course I don't know if is relevant in the study of odd perfect numbers (I try to study OPN from these equations, but I can not deduce a proposition about OPN): I know that you've articles about this subject.

Comment: There is no $n<100000000$ satisfying the equation.

Comment: Many thanks for your attention and help @didgogns